# Any inferences about the probability distribution of this variable?

Tags: probability-theory, normal-distribution

We have a random variable, $\mathbf{X} \in \mathbb{R}^+$ such that $\min_X \leq \mathbf{X} \leq \max_X$. Let $\mathbf{x_i}$ be the $i^{th}$ draw of the R.V $\mathbf{X}$.
Now, we define a new R.V $\mathbf{Y}$ such that:

$\mathbf{y}_i = \left\{ 
  \begin{array}{ c l }
    \ \mathbf{x_i} - thresh & \quad \textrm{if } \mathbf{x}_i \geq thresh \\
    0                 & \quad \textrm{otherwise}
  \end{array}
\right.$

I need to choose a $thresh$ that maximises the variance across all $\mathbf{y_i}$. Additional condition is  that $thresh \in (\min_X, \max_X) $. So my questions are:

**Part 1.** Can we get an estimate for the parameter $thresh$ without making any assumptions on the distribution of $\mathbf{X}$ apart from the knowledge of $\min_X$ and $\max_X$?

**Part 2.** If Part 1 is not possible, then can we get an estimate for $thresh$ by assuming $\mathbf{X}$ to have a gaussian distribution with ($\mu$, $\sigma$)

I am not sure if I should post this as two questions.

Comment: I might intuitively guess that a higher threshold would narrow the distribution of the $y_i$ and so variance of the $y_i$ would be maximised by any threshold $\le \min x_i$

Comment: sounds logical! but i need to do some simulation to check what happens when I do this, then i will come back to this comment. sorry, still a beginner; cannot think too deeply without monte carlo simulations :)

Comment: @Henry I can see from the wikipedia page on truncated normals that the variance is given by $$\sigma^2\left[1-\frac{\beta \phi(\beta)-\alpha \phi(\alpha)}{Z}-\left(\frac{\phi(\alpha)-\phi(\beta)}{Z}\right)^2\right]$$ but the Z is composed of $\mathbf{\phi}$ (cumulative distribution function). I thought maybe I can set a=0, b=b, and differentiate it w.r.t b to get the optimal threshold $b. But differentiating this part implies differentiating a differential, Which I cannot find a way to do at this point

Comment: Am I missing something, or would choosing the threshold to be bigger than $\max_X$ make the variance of $Y$ zero?

Comment: @user6247850 yes that would be 0. I have updated the question based on your comments. For any practical usefulness of y, the $thresh$ should be between $minX$ and $maxX$